# android sqlite3 table vacuum not working

Tags: android, database, sqlite, vacuum

I need to reorder the rowid sequentially after deleting some rows. Vacuum on table seems to be a good fit for the situation but for some reasons its not reordering the rowid.

```
sqlite> .schema inboxmessages 
CREATE TABLE InboxMessages(id text not null, title text not null, text text not null, senders_username text not null, created_at text not null, sender_image text not null, read text not null, Unique(id));

sqlite> select rowid, id from inboxmessages limit 5;
1|746915
3|746540
4|746195
5|745403
6|745371
sqlite> vacuum inboxmessages;
sqlite> select rowid, id from inboxmessages;
1|746915
3|746540
4|746195
5|745403
6|745371
```

whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) is not guaranteed to reorder `rowid` values, and if there is some INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column, it never will.

If you want to have specific values for your `rowid`s, you have to set them manually.

Please note that in most cases, it is a better idea to just leave gaps in the `rowid` sequence.